# Geoaccess privileges required for users - generating huge data

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

I have a web based application and each user is to be granted privileges called as "Geoaccess" which consists of States, Cities, and Branches or Post codes.

1. *States.* 
   Currently there are a total of 15 states.
2. *City.* 
   Each state has around 200+ cities. 
   200 cities x 15 states = 3000 Total Cities
3. *Branch or Post Code.* 
   Each city having branches = 10.  3000 cities x 10 branches = 30,000 Total Branches.

   Each city having postcodes =20.  3000 cities x 25 postcodes = 75000 Total Post Codes.

Rules:
1. Each user must have access to atleast a single branch or a post code (either only).
2. A user can have access to all the states. In this case, it also means that a user will have access to all branches or post codes.

**Question:** 
Logically with a little thought I can start structuring my solution by considering "Branches" or "Post Codes" as the last level of privilege.  But looking at the amount of data it will generate for each user I am into deep confusion here.

For example, if a user has permission for all states, that means I will have to populate either 75000 post codes or 30000 branches for this user.

Someone suggested me to use "-1" or some unique fixed value, in case a user needs "ALL" states, or cities, etc. I am not sure about this solution & I think of possible major maintenance issues popping up going towards this path.

I believe some folks here have been through this kind of situation. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting! A quick read says "isn't this like the concept of Roles?" - e.g. in ASP.Net membership. Another model is Category -> Parent Product -> SKUs...I'm curious as well!

Comment: Yes, Indeed it is.  I have a two set of privileges. The first set of privilege consists of roles that controls pages & functionality. The other set of privileges should control the geographic information that each user can access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be applying record-level security.

The best way is to have one Security table (each table `States`, `City`, `Branch or Post Code` and the catch-all permission `All` has its own ID - this should be as small a numeric datatype as possible, but I'm going to treat it as text for clarity in this answer):

```
UserID    TableID    RecordID
```

`RecordID` is nullable.

If a single record: `UserID = @x    TableID = 'All'    RecordID = Null` is entered, then that user has access to all the data.

If a user is granted access to a state's data: `UserID = @x    TableID = 'States'    RecordID = 1`, then that user has access to all cities and postcodes related to the state with ID = 1.

If a user is granted access to a city's data: `UserID = @x    TableID = 'City'    RecordID = 1`, then that user has access to all postcodes related to the city with ID = 1.

If a user is granted access to a Branch or Post Code's data: `UserID = @x    TableID = 'Branch or Post Code'    RecordID = 1`, then that user has access to only the Branch or Post Code with ID = 1.

If you wanted, you could add an extra bit field: `Deny`, that when is equal to 1, would deny access to that record.  This would be useful in scenarios similar to this: In City "X", the user has access to all but a few postcodes, so you would grant access to the city and deny access to the excluded postcodes.

Of course, if there is no permission record, the there is no access.

If you wanted something a little simpler, you could have one permission table per geographic table and the user record could have an "all access" bit field.

You would need to generate SQL that would filter your geographic tables according to the data in the permissions table.

**EDIT:**

Given the asker's concerns about data size, programming simplicity and the ease of maintaining the data:

1. This approach is designed to minimize data overhead.  When a user is granted (or denied) access to the entire data set or an entire sub-tree of the data tree, only one permission record is required.  It is only when users are granted access to branches piecemeal that the number of permission records per user can become very high.
2. There *is* a bit of coding work involved in aggregating the relevant data from the three tables into the permissions UI and applying permissions to the data, however this shouldn't be beyond the capabilities of a reasonably competent programmer to create - or understand, especially if properly commented and documented.  If it is expected that the programmers to which the application is to be handed are *not* reasonably competent, the permissions could be split into a separate set of permissions for each table, however this could be less useable to the DBAs.
3. Since this approach should minimize the number of permissions records that are associated with each user, it would be far easier to maintain than a grant-only permission structure purely at the lowest level, which would generate thousands of permission records that a DBA would have to maintain, an approach that would also be far more prone to errors of inclusion and omission.  The approach I have described might require only a handful of permission records per user, not thousands.

Comment: This solution seems very reasonable to me. In general, I have three main concerns.
1. Size of data, as it may become huge overtime. 
2. Simple enough to hand over to other developers / dba's.
3. Simple enough to visualize & control at the UI level for the application developers.   I understand that this solution addresses my 1st concern, and whereas I am not sure about the other concerns. Any comment on this plz.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering to my concerns. In all cases I'll have to live with the piecemeal case of branches. I will mark this as an answer. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Spit balling**:

How about this -

- Use an (existing/external) API to *validate a given user's full address* (this the "most important" part)
- Now you have "validated" - Zip, City, State
- Going back to "roles", assign a "role" to each "access level"

  - e.g. 1 for "admin" (State), 2 for "manager" (City), 3 for "member" (Zip)

So you wouldn't necessarily have to go all the way to zip/post code detail/db storage. I think City would be it - re: it's a *validated address*, so if the *City* is good to go (if there is a branch in that City), then zip is too.

Comment: This solution that I am seeking does not need user's location.  Each user will have a predefined list of locations (eg. State, City, Branch or Post Code) that they will have access to. Thanks.